# I want to populate a single element in a 2D array randomly with a single char value?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I randomly choose a single element out of a 2D array and fill that one element with char 'M'?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the code you tried with and we can help you find a mistake, if any.

Comment: `myArray[new Random().nextInt(myArray.length)] = 'M'`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
public class random2DChar {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char[][] char2DArr = new char[10][10];
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(char2DArr.length);
        char2DArr[x][x] = 'M';
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(char2DArr));
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be more random if the the x and y values were different. [x][y] instead of [x][x]

Comment: looks like it, but does it select a random element from the array?

Comment: `char2DArr[x][x]` this does select a random element from Array. As @miqdadamirali as said, we could make both dimensions random as well which would be `char2DArr[x][y]` in that case

Comment: well then you answered my question. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
// Your array of Char with the length of 5 by 5
char[][] arrayOfChar = new char[5][5];

// Generating a radom number with min being 0 and max being length - 1
Random rand = new Random();
int x = rand.nextInt(arrayOfChar[0].length);
int y = rand.nextInt(arrayOfChar[1].length);

// Random position in array assigned M
arrayOfChar[x][y] = 'M' ;
```

If you wanted an `int` array

```
// Your array of int with the length of 5 by 5
int[][] arrayOfInt = new int[5][5];

// Generating a radom number with min being 0 and max being length - 1
Random rand = new Random();
int x = rand.nextInt(arrayOfInt[0].length);
int y = rand.nextInt(arrayOfInt[1].length);

// Random position in array assigned number 8
arrayOfInt[x][y] = 8 ;
```

Comment: I need it for a 2D array. That looks like a 1D array...

Comment: @EmmaDillon updated it

Comment: looks like it, but does it select a random element from the array?

Comment: @EmmaDillon well wasn't that the idea! The arrayOfChar[x][y] chooses a random position based on the random numbers x and y and assigns it the M

Comment: yes! thanks for the help

Comment: @EmmaDillon Once you use the Random(), the results are never expected so that is pretty random

Comment: i have one more question. what if your array is already initialized as an int, like **int startMap[][];**? would you just change it from _char[][] arrayOfChar = new char[5][5];_ to **_int arrayOfChar = new int [5][5]_**?

Comment: @EmmaDillon In that case change you char to an int but then you can't assign an 'M' anymore because it is not an integer

Comment: @EmmaDillon I added more code for an example with an integer 2D array, hope that helps

Comment: so i should change my original array to a char then?

Comment: Yes you can, but again, you can't assign it an 'M' because it is not an integer. You can simply assign another integer like 1, or 4 or 19

Comment: i wanna keep it at an 'M' so i will just change my original _int_ array to a _char_ array

Comment: Yeah, you would have to keep it a char if you want to have an 'M'. Assigning an 'M' to an integer array would give you a compilation error. You could also have the array of type String, and that would hold a lot more than 'M' but will also use more space. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes it makes sense. thanks again